# Car Hesitate Sometimes While Driving

Tags: honda, accord, gears

I drive a Honda accord 2005 model v6.

Sometimes while driving and I get to slow down or when going up a hill my car hesitates for a while ( small jerk ).

What I mean is that, when I remove my leg from the gas pedal maybe on a hill or when I slow down and I want to accelerate again, it goes a little bit back and forward.

This only happens when am on a hill or when I slow down, every other time it's fine.

Please advise!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like deceleration fuel cutoff, which is a design feature.  I'm having trouble finding a good link to describe it right now, but the idea is that when you take your foot off the gas pedal, the fuel supply to the engine is cut off completely.  You may feel a slight jerk since the engine goes from supplying a small amount of acceleration to none.  When you begin accelerating again, you feel another jerk as the engine starts to provide power.  It's normal, even if it's slightly annoying, and it improves fuel economy slightly.  My 2006 Civic does the same thing.

I think it's more noticeable if you have a manual transmission.